# Use multiple foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm a beginner on Django and a bit more advanced on Python. I'm completely amazed by Django and I've been playing with it for something like a week now. I looked into a lot of tutorials and stackoverflow questions/answers and discovered a lot.

However, I'm still a little bit lost when it comes to OneToMany / Foreign Key relationships and the way to access it. I had a look at the "Library/Book" example of the official documentation but still trying to figure out how to solve the below problem.

**[Explanations]**

- I have Users *(already created)*
- To the Django-built Users, I added a Profile (OneToOneField)
- The Profile contains only one item for each User: a title (Foreign Key)
- The Title in turn comes from a existing list of available Titles
- Finally, I have Opportunities (a class) which has one User linked (Foreign Key)

*in models.py*

```
class ProfileStatus(models.Model):
    """ table of available titles for users  """
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.status

class Profile(models.Model):
    """ add a title to an existing user """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.ForeignKey(ProfileStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class OpportunityStatus(models.Model):
    """ status for an opportunity """
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.status

class Opportunity(models.Model):
    """ An opportunity """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    director = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.ForeignKey(OpportunityStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**[What I'm looking for]**

I would like to know how you would:

- For the Users having 'Director' as title
- get a list of the opportunities where they are linked as director
- then filter this list down to the opportunities that have the status 'alive' to be then passed to a view (that I can manage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you use the double underscore syntax to follow relations. So, for example, to get users who have the title of director, you would do:

```
User.objects.filter(profile__title__status='Director')
```

However, if you want Opportunities rather than Users, you need to start with the Opportunity model. So:

```
Opportunity.objects.filter(status__status='alive', director__profile__title__status='Director')
```

This query might be slightly less horrible if you made Opportunity point to Profile, rather than User.

Comment: Awesome, the second option is exactly what I've been desperately looking for (__director__profile__title_status...) ! The status='alive' however needs to be status=ID rather than the keyword, do you have an idea how I could have status='alive' rather than status=ID ? 

Thank you so much for your kind help ! Unfortunately I cannot vote 'cause I'm new to Stack but as soon as I got enough points, I'll come back to vote for it :)

Comment: I updated it, it should have been `status__status`. You might want to think about the names a bit more, it's confusing to have a foreign key named the same as the actual field in the destination model. Maybe OpportunityStatus and ProfileStatus should have `name` fields rather than `status`.

Comment: Yes indeed, you're completely right on the names - it's confusing. Everything sorted, thanks !!